# What index should i put in for the insert function in stack?

Tags: python, palindrome, stack

I am trying to write a program to check if entered string is a palindrome, using the basic concept of stacks. I am confused what index to enter in the stack1.insert function. Please help? Or do you think there is an even more simpler approach to this?

```
def palindrome(str1):
        stack1 = []
        palInd = False
        for chr in str1:
            stack1.insert(0, chr)
        for i in range(len(str1)-1):
            if str1[i]==stack1.pop():
                palInd = True
            else:
                palInd = False
        return palInd

    print palindrome("madam")
```

Comment: Have a look at [collections.deque](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#deque-objects), it can be used as a stack.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Ashwini Chaudhary notes, this problem is easily solved using a deque, which allows easy popping from both ends.

```
import collections

def is_palindrome(string):
    palindrome = collections.deque(string)
    while len(palindrome) > 1:
        if palindrome.popleft() != palindrome.pop():
            return False
    return True
```

Answer (score 0):

Though this problem can definitely be solved with stacks, I think I have a simple iterative approach to offer:

```
def palindrome(string):
    chars = list(string)
    for i in range(0,len(chars)/2):
            if (chars[i] != chars[len(chars)-i-1]):
                    return False
    return True
```

And here's a test:

```
 print palindrome("sees")
 print palindrome("racecar")
 print palindrome("not a palindrome")
 print palindrome("madam")
```

Which results in:

```
True
True
False
True
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you're looking for simpler approaches... The easiest way is just to use slicing:

```
def is_pal(a):
    return a == a[::-1]
```

There are lots of variations on this, mostly involving iteration from the ends.

```
def is_pal(a):
    return a == ''.join(reversed(a))

def is_pal(a):
    forwards,backwards = iter(a), reversed(a)
    return all(x==y for x,y in zip(forwards,backwards))
```

Technically if you're being optimal (processing some GIANT palindrome, maybe) you don't need to iterate over the whole string, just meet in the middle:

```
def is_pal(a):
    halflen = len(a) // 2
    forwards,backwards = iter(a[:halflen]), reversed(a[halflen:])
    return all(x==y for x,y in zip(forwards,backwards))
```

This ends up being near exactly what you'd be doing with a deque popping off both ends.